# Can I sell smoke (cigarettes)?

Tags: halal-haram

I am deciding to sell cigarettes or smoke. Is this permissible, as people who these products are addicted to them, and by selling to them, it’s harming them. Please kindly let me know if there is any Hadith against this or supporting it.

Comment: Assalamualaikum https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28242/is-tobacco-sale-haram

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://islamqa.info/en/answers/87800/it-is-not-permissible-to-sell-cigarettes-even-if-you-are-working-in-the-store